# Deploying Azure function to linux consumption plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cloud, azure-function-app, azure-linux

I need some help deploying my  dotnet core functions app to a linux consumptionplan machine in azure, using github actions.

Right now when I deploy nothing happens in azure (no functions to be seen anywhere), yet the logs in github actions sais everything is OK (?!).

I don't know if anyone has some tips but I'm hoping someone who knows what's wrong can help.

I've successfully deployed using vscode with azure extensions. When I do it all works, with a difference: the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE gets set to a URL that gets generated after deploy by vscode.
Here's my github file (inspiration from [Here](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/FunctionApp/linux-dotnet-functionapp-on-azure.yml), I've copied it to exact with the same bad result):

```
name: Build, Test & Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  OUTPUT_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/.output
  DOTNET_VERSION: "3.1"
  APP_NAME: "the-name"
  
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout GitHub Action
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} Environment
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: Test
        run: dotnet test
        
      - name: Publish dotnet app
        run: dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ${{ env.OUTPUT_PATH }}
          
      - name: Run Azure Functions Action
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: fa
        with:
          package: ${{ env.OUTPUT_PATH }}
          app-name: ${{ env.APP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE  }}
```

Comment: If you configured your RBAC correctly then when you go your Azure Resource Group /Subscription you will be able to see more details about the Deployment.

Comment: `secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE` - Did you upload your correct publish profile in github secret?

Comment: Thanks! I have to see if I can find that.

Comment: Yeah, the publish profile should be correct.